# Kubuntu 16.04 Libreoffice top toolbar bug

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

I've a problem with fresh Kubuntu install with Libreoffice.

The top toolbar is broken.
[image]

Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried changing video drivers?

Comment: Nope, how to do this :). Also here is only one program that broken.